# How to use AutoMapper 9 with static implementation without DI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, automapping

I want to create static implementation of AutoMapper without dependency injection. I'm using ASP.NET CORE 2.2 and AutoMapper 9.
I've found similar topic:

[How to use AutoMapper 9.0.0 in Asp.Net Web Api 2 without dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190428/how-to-use-automapper-9-0-0-in-asp-net-web-api-2-without-dependency-injection)

Is there any simpler way to create static implementation without DI?

Comment: If you're using ASP.NET Core, is there a reason you object to using it without DI?

Comment: I have a lot of controllers in my project so every time I have to use DI to map objects and I think that AutoMapper should have differents approaches not only DI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply build a mapper from the mapper configuration. An example is provided in the AutoMapper [docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper), which I have reproduced here:

```
// use cfg to configure AutoMapper
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()); 

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
// or
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
OrderDto dto = mapper.Map<OrderDto>(order);
```

Then you could simply set a `static` field/property somewhere in your project to hold `mapper`.